# JFace: ColumnLabelProvider override CellEditorLabelProvider

Tags: jface

I am implementing a JFace `TableViewer` where some of the columns are `ComboBoxViewerCellEditor`.

I am setting `ColumnLabelProvider` to each column and on addition to the columns with the combo box I am also setting `EditingSupport`.

The `EditingSupport` contain encapsulate also a `LabelProvider` within the `ComboBoxViewerCellEditor`.

All implementation is based on JFace MVC – i.e. viewers and providers without implementing event listeners.

The behavior is a s follow:

1. launching the table the values displayed OK – i.e. column label provider provide the right data.
2. launching the combo box within a column the values in the dropdown list shown OK, and selecting value works fine – i.e. combo box shows new value and data model change to new value
3. when leaving the combo box the value (label) shown in the combo box is back the one provided by the column label provider (in #1).

it seems that either I should not use both label providers or somehow refresh the data in the column label provider.

I am attaching my code, please look into columnViewer `columnViewerTargetObjectModelAttr` which has both `ColumnLabelProvider` and `EditingSupport`.

I'll be grateful for any advice,
thanks.
Yaron.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ArrayContentProvider;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.CellEditor;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ColumnLabelProvider;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ColumnViewer;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ComboBoxViewerCellEditor;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.EditingSupport;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ISelection;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ISelectionChangedListener;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.IStructuredSelection;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.LabelProvider;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.SelectionChangedEvent;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TableViewer;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TableViewerColumn;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.custom.CCombo;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table;

import myPackage.DataObjectAssociation;
import myPackage.DataObjectAssociations;
import myPackage.DataObjectAttribute;
import myPackage.DataObjectAttributeUI;
import myPackage.DataObjectUI;

public class ObjectModelAssociationPageMVC extends
        ObjectModaelGenerationWizardPage {
    private TableViewer omTableViewer;
    private TableViewer assocTableViewer;
    private Composite container;

    public ObjectModelAssociationPageMVC(ISelection selection,
            HanaServicesAdapter hanaServicesAdapter) {
        super("wizardPage", selection, hanaServicesAdapter);
        setTitle("Generate Object Model");
        setDescription("This wizard generates object models based on selected tables and     views");
        this.hanaServicesAdapter = hanaServicesAdapter;
    }

    @Override
    public void createControl(Composite parent) {

        // main container
        this.container = new Composite(parent, SWT.NULL);
        GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(1, true);
        container.setLayout(layout);

        // om container
        Composite omContainer = new Composite(container, SWT.NULL);
        omContainer.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, false,
                1, 1));
        GridLayout omLayout = new GridLayout(1, true);
        omContainer.setLayout(omLayout);

        // ----- Objects List Label ------
        Label objectModelLabel = new Label(omContainer, SWT.NULL);
        objectModelLabel.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true,
                false, 1, 1));
        objectModelLabel.setText("Create Object Models Association:");

        // ----- Objects List ------
        omTableViewer = new TableViewer(omContainer, SWT.BORDER | SWT.SELECTED);
        omTableViewer.setContentProvider(new ArrayContentProvider());
        omTableViewer
            .addSelectionChangedListener(new     ObjectModelTableViewerSelectionListener());

        Table omTable = omTableViewer.getTable();
        omTable.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, false, false, 1,
                1));
        omTable.setLinesVisible(true);
        omTable.setHeaderVisible(true);
        GridData omTableGridData = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true,
                false, 1, 1);
        omTableGridData.heightHint = omTable.getItemHeight() * 10
                + omTable.getHeaderHeight();
        omTable.setLayoutData(omTableGridData);
        // Column Object Name
        TableViewerColumn col = new TableViewerColumn(omTableViewer, SWT.NONE);
        col.getColumn().setText("Object Model Name");
        col.getColumn().setWidth(200);
        col.setLabelProvider(new ObjectModelNameColumnLabelProvider());

        // Associations List Container
        Composite assocContainer = new Composite(container, SWT.NULL);
    assocContainer.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true,
            false, 1, 1));
    GridLayout assocLayout = new GridLayout(2, false);
    assocContainer.setLayout(assocLayout);

        // ----- Associations List Label ------
        Label assocLabel = new Label(assocContainer, SWT.NULL);
        assocLabel.setText("Associations:");
        assocLabel.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, false,
                2, 1));

        // Associations Table Container
        Composite assocTableContainer = new Composite(assocContainer, SWT.NULL);
        assocTableContainer.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL,
                true, false, 1, 1));
        GridLayout assocTableLayout = new GridLayout(1, true);
        assocTableContainer.setLayout(assocTableLayout);

        // Associations add/remove buttons container
        Composite assocButtonsContainer = new Composite(assocContainer,
                SWT.NULL);
        assocButtonsContainer.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL,
                true, false, 1, 1));
        GridLayout assocButtonsLayout = new GridLayout(1, true);
        assocButtonsContainer.setLayout(assocButtonsLayout);

        // ----- Associations List ------
        assocTableViewer = new TableViewer(assocTableContainer, SWT.BORDER
                | SWT.MULTI | SWT.FULL_SELECTION);
        assocTableViewer.setContentProvider(new ArrayContentProvider());
        Table assocTable = assocTableViewer.getTable();
        GridData assocTableGridData = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true,
                false, 1, 1);
    assocTableGridData.heightHint = assocTable.getItemHeight() * 10
            + assocTable.getHeaderHeight();
    assocTable.setLayoutData(assocTableGridData);
    assocTable.setLinesVisible(false);
    assocTable.setHeaderVisible(true);

        TableViewerColumn columnViewerAssocName = new TableViewerColumn(
                assocTableViewer, SWT.NONE);
        columnViewerAssocName.getColumn().setText("Association Name");
        columnViewerAssocName
                .setLabelProvider(new AssociationNameColumnLabelProvider());
        columnViewerAssocName.getColumn().pack();

        TableViewerColumn columnViewerSourceObjectModelAttr = new TableViewerColumn(
                assocTableViewer, SWT.NONE);
        columnViewerSourceObjectModelAttr.getColumn().setText(
                "Source Object Model Attribute");
        columnViewerSourceObjectModelAttr
                .setLabelProvider(new SourceObjectModelAttributeNameColumnLabelProvider());
        columnViewerSourceObjectModelAttr.getColumn().pack();

        TableViewerColumn columnViewerTargetObjectModel = new TableViewerColumn(
                assocTableViewer, SWT.NONE);
        columnViewerTargetObjectModel.getColumn()
                .setText("Target Object Model");
        columnViewerTargetObjectModel
                .setLabelProvider(new TargetObjectModelNameColumnLabelProvider());

        EditingSupport targetObjectModelColumnEditingSupport = new     TargetObjectModelColumnEditingSupport(
                columnViewerTargetObjectModel.getViewer());
        columnViewerTargetObjectModel
            .setEditingSupport(targetObjectModelColumnEditingSupport);

    columnViewerTargetObjectModel.getColumn().pack();

    TableViewerColumn columnViewerTargetObjectModelAttr = new TableViewerColumn(
            assocTableViewer, SWT.NONE);
    columnViewerTargetObjectModelAttr.getColumn().setText(
            "Target Object Model Attribute");
    columnViewerTargetObjectModelAttr
            .setLabelProvider(new TargetObjectModelAttributeNameColumnLabelProvider());
    EditingSupport targetObjectModelAttributeColumnEditingSupport = new TargetObjectModelAttributeColumnEditingSupport(
            columnViewerTargetObjectModel.getViewer());
    columnViewerTargetObjectModelAttr
            .setEditingSupport(targetObjectModelAttributeColumnEditingSupport);
    columnViewerTargetObjectModelAttr.getColumn().pack();

    TableViewerColumn columnViewerAssocCardinality = new TableViewerColumn(
            assocTableViewer, SWT.NONE);
    columnViewerAssocCardinality.getColumn().setText("Cardinality");
    columnViewerAssocCardinality
            .setLabelProvider(new CardinalityColumnLabelProvider());
    columnViewerAssocCardinality.getColumn().pack();

    assocTable.pack();

    // ----- Associations List Buttons ------
    Button addAssocButton = new Button(assocButtonsContainer, SWT.PUSH);
    addAssocButton.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, false,
            false, 1, 1));
    addAssocButton.setText("Add");
    Button removeAssocButton = new Button(assocButtonsContainer, SWT.PUSH);
    removeAssocButton.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, false,
            false, 1, 1));
    removeAssocButton.setText("Remove");

    // ------------ Create Objects ------------------
    setControl(container);
}

class ObjectModelTableViewerSelectionListener implements
        ISelectionChangedListener {
    @Override
    public void selectionChanged(SelectionChangedEvent event) {
        IStructuredSelection selection;
        DataObjectUI dataObjectUI;
        DataObjectAssociations dataObjectAssociations;
        DataObjectAssociation[] dataObjectAssociation = null;
        selection = (IStructuredSelection) omTableViewer.getSelection();
        dataObjectUI = (DataObjectUI) selection.getFirstElement();
        dataObjectAssociations = dataObjectUI.getAssociations();
        if (dataObjectAssociations != null) {
            List<DataObjectAssociation> list = dataObjectAssociations
                    .getAssociation();
            dataObjectAssociation = list
                    .toArray(new DataObjectAssociation[list.size()]);
        }
        assocTableViewer.setInput(dataObjectAssociation);
        // cellEditor.setInput(hanaServicesAdapter.getSelectedTablesViews()
        // .toArray());
    }
}

@Override
public void setVisible(boolean visible) {
    super.setVisible(visible);
    if (visible) {
        omTableViewer.setContentProvider(new ArrayContentProvider());
        omTableViewer.setInput(hanaServicesAdapter.getSelectedTablesViews()
                .toArray());

    }
}

class ObjectModelNameColumnLabelProvider extends ColumnLabelProvider {
    @Override
    public String getText(Object element) {
        DataObjectUI dataObjectUI = (DataObjectUI) element;
        return dataObjectUI.getFileName();
    }
}

class AssociationNameColumnLabelProvider extends ColumnLabelProvider {
    @Override
    public String getText(Object element) {
        DataObjectAssociation dataObjectAssociation = (DataObjectAssociation) element;
        return dataObjectAssociation.getName();
    }
}

class TargetObjectModelNameColumnLabelProvider extends ColumnLabelProvider {
    @Override
    public String getText(Object element) {
        DataObjectAssociation dataObjectAssociation = (DataObjectAssociation) element;
        return dataObjectAssociation.getTarget();
    }
}

class TargetObjectModelAttributeNameColumnLabelProvider extends
        ColumnLabelProvider {
    @Override
    public String getText(Object element) {
        DataObjectAssociation dataObjectAssociation = (DataObjectAssociation) element;
        return dataObjectAssociation.getTargetAttribute();
    }
}

class SourceObjectModelAttributeNameColumnLabelProvider extends
        ColumnLabelProvider {
    @Override
    public String getText(Object element) {
        DataObjectAssociation dataObjectAssociation = (DataObjectAssociation) element;
        return dataObjectAssociation.getSourceAttribute();              
    }
}

class CardinalityColumnLabelProvider extends ColumnLabelProvider {
    @Override
    public String getText(Object element) {
        DataObjectAssociation dataObjectAssociation = (DataObjectAssociation) element;
        return dataObjectAssociation.getCardinality().toString();
    }
}

public final class TargetObjectModelColumnEditingSupport extends
        EditingSupport {
    private ComboBoxViewerCellEditor cellEditor;

    private TargetObjectModelColumnEditingSupport(ColumnViewer viewer) {
        super(viewer);
    }

    @Override
    protected CellEditor getCellEditor(Object element) {
        cellEditor = new ComboBoxViewerCellEditor((Composite) getViewer()
                .getControl(), SWT.READ_ONLY);
        cellEditor.setLabelProvider(new LabelProvider() {
            public String getText(Object element) {
                return ((DataObjectUI) element).getFileName();
            }
        });
        cellEditor.setContentProvider(new ArrayContentProvider());
        String target = ((DataObjectAssociation) element).getTarget();
        CCombo combo = cellEditor.getViewer().getCCombo();
        // combo.select(combo.indexOf(target));
        combo.setText(target);
        cellEditor.setInput(hanaServicesAdapter.getSelectedTablesViews()
                .toArray());
        return cellEditor;
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean canEdit(Object element) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected Object getValue(Object element) {
        if (element instanceof DataObjectAssociation) {
            DataObjectAssociation data = (DataObjectAssociation) element;
            return data.getTarget();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void setValue(Object element, Object value) {
        if (element instanceof DataObjectAssociation
                && value instanceof DataObjectUI) {
            DataObjectAssociation data = (DataObjectAssociation) element;
            String newValue = ((DataObjectUI) value).getFileName();
            /* only set new value if it differs from old one */
            if (!data.getTarget().equals(newValue)) {
                data.setTarget(newValue);
            }
        }
    }

}

public final class TargetObjectModelAttributeColumnEditingSupport extends
        EditingSupport {
    private ComboBoxViewerCellEditor cellEditor;

    private TargetObjectModelAttributeColumnEditingSupport(
            ColumnViewer viewer) {
        super(viewer);
    }

    @Override
    protected CellEditor getCellEditor(Object element) {
        cellEditor = new ComboBoxViewerCellEditor((Composite) getViewer()
                .getControl(), SWT.READ_ONLY);
        cellEditor.setLabelProvider(new LabelProvider() {
            public String getText(Object element) {
                return ((DataObjectAttributeUI) element).getName();
            }
        });
        cellEditor.setContentProvider(new ArrayContentProvider());

        CCombo combo = cellEditor.getViewer().getCCombo();

        // String targetObjectModel = targetObjectCombo.getText();

        DataObjectUI dataObjectUI = hanaServicesAdapter
                .getDataObjectUI(((DataObjectAssociation) element)
                        .getTarget());
        cellEditor.setInput(dataObjectUI.getSelectedAttributesUI()
                .toArray());
        String attribute = ((DataObjectAssociation) element)
                .getTargetAttribute();
        combo.setText(attribute);
        return cellEditor;
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean canEdit(Object element) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected Object getValue(Object element) {
        if (element instanceof DataObjectAssociation) {
            DataObjectAssociation data = (DataObjectAssociation) element;
            return data.getTargetAttribute();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void setValue(Object element, Object value) {
        if (element instanceof DataObjectAssociation
                && value instanceof DataObjectAttributeUI) {
            DataObjectAssociation data = (DataObjectAssociation) element;
            String newValue = ((DataObjectAttributeUI) value).getName();
            /* only set new value if it differs from old one */
            if (!data.getTargetAttribute().equals(newValue)) {
                data.setTargetAttribute(newValue);
            }
        }
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you might want to try an update on setValue().

```
    if (!data.getTargetAttribute().equals(newValue)) {
        data.setTargetAttribute(newValue);
        update(element, null);
    }
```

Comment: any more explaination

Comment: It is a way to signal the viewers label providers to update only one element. Even better would be to set column properties for each column, so you can update for ONE element, ONE column, and not every column.